# How to call a method used in another WPF window in c#?

Tags: c#, wpf, methods

I am creating a game like system which contains a trainingSession window and a testSession window.  In the trainingSession window i have created a method - public void stage() which contain the neccesary data to run the session.   Now i want this exact same method used in the testSession window.  But how can i call it?  I do not want to copy and paste the entie method again.

Is there a way i can do this?
Thanks, e.mack

or is it possible to have this method in its own class file, which then can be called by both the trainingSession class and the testSession class... but then there would be alot of parameters needing to be passed over.

Comment: Move the method to a common ViewModel.

Answer (score 1):

That's what inheritance is for!

Create a mustinherit class called baseSession. That's where method stage() goes.

Now, say that trainingSession and testSession both derive from baseSession. Voilà! -- stage() is now part of both testSession and trainingSession.

Comment: Thanks alan for your reply. My stage() method contains assigning data to button controls that are created in xaml for both training and test classes. so When i added my stage() in to new class file, i get syntex errors because it is not linked to the xaml page where the controls are.. is there any way round this?   Forgot to mention, im using c#. does this support mustinherit class?